# When typing, comment bar opens all the time in wp admin

Tags: wp-admin

Is there any way to turn it off with a snippet? I found a lot of posts about this but none of the solutions removes the comment bubble from my top bar. I can't write anything anywhere because it keeps opening.

Comment: Welcome! You'll need to be more specific about your problem for anyone to give a clear answer. This isn't normal WordPress behaviour, so something custom will have been done to the site to change it's behaviour. Please attach a screenshot of what "comment bar" you are referring to, and a link to the articles you've tried to fix the problem would help as well. Also any code you've written related to the comment bar would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.